# when store file in laravel failed to open stream

Tags: laravel, file, storage, fopen, laravel-storage

When I try get link from url and store file with this link in storage i have this error 
my code

```
foreach ($value['subtitles'] as $d => $m) {
                $guzzle = new Client();
                $response = $guzzle->get($m['url']);
                $name = basename($m['url']);
                $new = str_replace('dd', 'ff', $name);
                 Storage::disk('public')->put('/zirnevis/' . $new, $response->getBody());
                File::create([
                    'title' => $new,
                    'type' => 'zirnevis'
                ]);

            }
```

and erorr

```
fopen(C:\wamp64\www\jahanzirnevis\storage\app/public\zirnevis/download?d=YTo1OntzOjE6InMiO3M6NTY6Ii9zdWJ0aXRsZXMvcml2ZXJkYWxlLWZvdXJ0aC1zZWFzb24vZmFyc2lfcGVyc2lhbi8yMDY1MDM5IjtzOjE6InAiO3M6MjM6InJpdmVyZGFsZS1mb3VydGgtc2Vhc29uIjtzOjE6InQiO3M6Mzk6IlJJVkVSREFMRSBOZXcgWW9yayBDb21pYyBDb24gMjAxOSBWaWRlbyI7czoxOiJvIjtpOjY2NjM7czoxOiJpIjtiOjA7fQ==): failed to open stream: No error
```

Comment: did you check permissions?

Comment: These slashes don't look consistent, how do you generate that path?